# Create a fixed navigation that slides away after scrolling for a short distance and returns when scrolling back up

Tags: jquery, css

I am attempting to create a fixed navigation which slides away after the user scrolls downs a short distance and then returns in to fixed view after scrolling back up. The code below works to a degree but jumps, without the smooth slides that you get when scrolling up and down on the navigation at:

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var previousScroll = 0,
    headerOrgOffset = $('.nav').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(currentScroll + " and " + previousScroll + " and " + headerOrgOffset);
    if(currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
            $('.nav').fadeOut();
        } else {
            $('.nav').fadeIn();
            $('.nav').addClass('scrolling');
            $('.anchor').addClass('anchorpaddingtop');
        }
    } else {
         $('.anchor').removeClass('anchorpaddingtop');
         $('.nav').removeClass('scrolling');   
    }
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
});
```

My example is at http://sandbox.jonathanbeech.co.uk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this:

Playground - **http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/GdLlK**

```
(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll.getDirection', getScrollDirection);

    var lastScrollTop = '',
        sticky      = $('#header'),
        stickyH     = sticky.height(),
        sensetivity = 16, // lower is more sensetive
        stickyPos   = 0,
        lastDownPos, delta, st;

    function getScrollDirection(){
        st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

        if( st > lastScrollTop ){  // && sticky.hasClass('sticky')
            // console.log( 'down' );

            if( stickyPos <= -stickyH && sticky.hasClass('sticky') ){
                stickyPos = -stickyH;
                sticky.removeClass('sticky').removeAttr('style');
            }
            else{
                sticky.css('top', stickyPos);
                stickyPos -= sensetivity / 2;
            }
            lastDownPos = st;
        }
        else{
            // console.log( 'up' );
            delta = Math.abs(lastDownPos - st);
            if( !sticky.hasClass('sticky') ){
                stickyPos = -stickyH;
                sticky.addClass('sticky').css({ position:'fixed', top: stickyPos });
            }
            else if( stickyPos < 0 ){
                stickyPos += (delta / sensetivity);
                if( stickyPos > 0 ) stickyPos = 0;
                sticky.css('top', stickyPos);
            }
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thankyou for the thoughts. Your code pen is just what I am after. However the way my html and css works seems to break the functionality. I'm hoping there is a way to prevent the ugly jumping effect as soon as the page is scrolled down on my site with my code.

Comment: it jumps because the header changes it's class to `scrolling` which gives is `position:fixed` which takes it out of the scope of the page layout, thus, you have a sudden "jump". just make it be `position:absolute` and correct your layout accordingly, then on scroll it will change to be `fixed`.

Comment: Thats great, I made the nav bar position absolute and then added some margin top to the band below which is just the job. Many thanks.